# Armstrong Numbers between 1-10000 using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out Armstrong Numbers from 1-10000, and my question is that **there are "four 1s" when i compile and run**, and I would like to ask  which part of coding that I did wrong, and what part of code should be revised if I want only one 1 to be printed out. Other than that, all the others Armstrong Numbers output correctly. It's my first time asking here and I hope people who sees this would give me some advice.
Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("Armstrong Numbers from 1-10000:\n");
int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4; 
int i;

for(i=1; i<10000; i++){

    digit4=i/1000;
    digit3=(i%1000)/100;
    digit2=((i%1000)%100)/10;
    digit1=((i%1000)%100)%10;

    //one digit number 
    if(i<10){
        if(i==digit1)printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    //two digit number
    if(10<=i<100){
        int output100 = digit1*digit1 + digit2*digit2;
        if(i==output100)printf("%d\n",i);
    }
    //three digit number 
    if(100<=i<=999){
        int output1000 = digit1*digit1*digit1 + digit2*digit2*digit2 + digit3*digit3*digit3;
        if(i==output1000){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    //four digit number
    if(1000<=i<=10000){
        int output10000 = digit1*digit1*digit1*digit1 + digit2*digit2*digit2*digit2 + digit3*digit3*digit3*digit3 + digit4*digit4*digit4*digit4;
        if(i==output10000){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing all these... wierd things, convert your number to a string, and check for each chararcter if its a '1'

Comment: [OT]: `((i%1000)%100)%10` is simply `i % 10` and `((i%1000)%100)/10` is `(i % 100) / 10` or `(i / 10) % 10`.

Comment: use "else if" instead of "if" on the 2nd , 3rd and 4th "if"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compile with warnings:

```
if(1000<=i<=10000){
```

> warning: comparisons like ‘X<=Y<=Z’ do not have their mathematical
>   meaning [-Wparentheses]

Do you mean `if(i >= 1000 && i < 10000){` ?

Comment: He's not showing a real answer to the code, OP is aking for advices and is obvioulsy not aware of some C functionnality.

Comment: "Other than that, all the others Armstrong Numbers output correctly", Even if the answer shows a problem, thats not OP's problem (IMHO)

Comment: I also got downvoted sometimes for making imcomplete answers, but this one does not even solve anything here

Comment: I didn't downvote, but, yes, this answer is more of a comment.

Comment: Correct answer (if not fully explained). It is because of the syntax errors in the comparisons, that `1` is being printed in each of the 4 sections - instead of just the first.

Comment: @Treycos so this **if(1000<=i<=10000)** looks ok for you?

Comment: @Michi It obviously isn't, but its off-topic there, this should be a comment

Comment: @Treycos Then why are saying that this Answer solves nothing?

Comment: @Treycos: Fixing the 3 comparisons solves the issue: [Demo](https://ideone.com/CT9K6O)

Comment: this is the cause of the problem, when i = 1, the first if is true( for obvious reasons) , the second if is true too ( 10 <= i < 100) is evaluated from left to right like this (10 <= i) and this evaluates to 0, what remains is (0 < 100) which is true.. so each "if" is executed always except the first one

Comment: @Keine Lust  Thank you for you answer. By changing the comparisons to the form you advised, the result is correct now. And, thanks to all the comments too, I will keep learning and coding!!

Comment: By the way, following Armstrong Numbers rules, your outputs are wrong 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.... aren't Armstrong Numbers

Comment: @Treycos: Look at [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number). But `02`, `002`, `0002` are not Amstrong number.

Comment: @Jarod42 Following this definition, my answer works perfectly :  http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html